Ansible: create symlink based on whether a file exists or not
I want to create a symlink (soft link) based on whether a file exists or not. I am using the when/register to try and achieve this but I guess I'm doing something wrong. Here's my playbook;
- name: Check if /usr/local/bin/brew exists
  stat:
    path: /usr/local/bin/brew
  register: file_status_intel

- name: Check if /opt/homebrew/bin/brew exists
  stat:
    path: /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
  register: file_status_arm

- name: Create library symlink to Java for intel
  file:
    src: "/usr/local/bin/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk"
    dest: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk"
    state: link
  when: file_status_intel.stat.exists
  tags: selenium

- name: Create library symlink to Java for Mac M1, M2, M3
  file:
    src: "/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk"
    dest: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk"
    state: link
  when: file_status_arm.stat.exists
  tags: selenium

however I still get error;
fatal: [tyr-mac-1-dev]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "gid": 0, "group": "wheel", "mode": "0755", "msg": "src file does not exist, use \"force=yes\" if you really want to create the link: /usr/local/bin/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk", "owner": "root", "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk", "size": 45, "src": "/usr/local/bin/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk", "state": "link", "uid": 0}


You are not getting the stat of the file you are trying to link to.  What does one have to do with the other? It is telling you the src does not exists which has nothing to do with the file existing in your conditional statement.

Thanks for your reply @Squashman , so how can I achieve what I want please. Any help would be appreciated

Maybe explain why you are checking if brew exists and what that has to do with making a link to java.

Yes of course @Squashman . Reason behind that could be explained here; https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk@11 Note the part where it says;
For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with     sudo ln -sfn $HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk Now also note that depending on what Mac machine is being used, brew is installed somewhat different; explained here -> https://mac.install.guide/homebrew/3 hence why I'm going through this trouble

If the source doesn't exist that most likely means you do not have OpenJKD 11 installed.  The error message is pretty clear.  The source file does not exist.

it does though that's the thing; java -version openjdk version "11.0.16.1" 2022-08-12 OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.16.1+0) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.16.1+0, mixed mode)

I would do something like that:
- name: Install java11 with brew
  community.general.homebrew:
    pkg: 'openjdk@11'

- name: Get brew prefix
  ansible.builtin.command:
    cmd: 'brew --prefix'
  register: brew_prefix

- name: Create jdk symlink
  ansible.builtin.file:
    src: '{{ brew_prefix.stdout}}/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk'
    dest: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk'
    state: link


Still get the same issue unfortunately; fatal: [tyr-mac-2-test]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "gid": 0, "group": "wheel", "mode": "0755", "msg": "src file does not exist, use \"force=yes\" if you really want to create the link: /opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk", "owner": "root", "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk", "size": 45, "src": "/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk", "state": "link", "uid": 0}

I found the issue finally...
Where I have the following src, it should be looking under /usr/local/opt and NOT /usr/local/bin.
- name: Create library symlink to Java for intel
  file:
    src: "/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk"
    dest: "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk"
    state: link
  when: file_status_intel.stat.exists
  tags: selenium

